# App notification sound defaulting to off in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uilocalnotification

Starting in iOS 7, my app's entry in Notification Center has sounds defaulting to off for some users. Since my app is an alarm clock and needs to use UILocalNotifications all the time, this obviously is a major problem. Does anyone know what might have changed to cause this problem? And is there anything that can be done to address it?

Comment: I have a same issue like you.. I hope someone tell you a solution..

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm having the same errors as you guys... if someone installs the app for the first time, sounds are deactivated by default..

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that uses notifications too (timing meeting agenda items), and I agree that notification sounds are critical for an app like this.  But app can't override the settings in Settings -> Notification Center, so the user must set the notification sounds there.

What I found was that the settings stayed the same when I upgraded the phone to iOS 7, but a re-install of the app can trash them - if the app was deleted before the upgrade. Deleting the app and re-installing (on iOS7 and earlier) doesn't change the notification settings.